# How to apply Mesh Sequence Cache modifier to imported meshes

Tags: modifiers

I imported an animation to Blender, its format is Alembic. Once the file is imported, all the meshes (in my case 900 meshes) have a Mesh Sequence Cache Modifier. This modifier has all the ShapeKey animations, if I don't apply it, the meshes lose Shapekeys. I tried the Copy Attribute add-on, but it deletes the modifiers, which means all the Shapekeys are lost. Is there a way to execute the "apply" button on the same modifier that is on multiple meshes, so the apply button on all modifiers gets applied?

Please note that I don't want to copy modifiers from 1 mesh to others. I want to execute the "apply" button on the same modifier that already exists on other meshes. I also tried the Alt+Click, it works with other options, but not the apply button in the modifier.

Please help

Comment: Would this help? https://blenderartists.org/t/mesh-sequence-cache-modifier-how-do-you-use-it/1150372